# Did Ravana from Ramayana lust over Goddess Parvati?

Tags: ramayana, ravana, parvati

I was reading an [answer on quora](https://www.quora.com/If-Ravana-did-not-touch-Sita-while-kidnapping-her-and-Ram-casts-doubt-on-Sita-and-burns-her-in-pyre-who-is-the-good-guy/answer/Rohan-Goswami-78?ch=10&share=eb7c199c&srid=ucZAt6) which states that Ravana lusted over Goddess Parvati.

**Did Ravana lust on goddess Parvati ?**

Comment: I think as per Valmiki Ramayana, No. And as per Shiva Purana, it was Sati and not Parvati during Ravana's time..may be some other Ramayana or  Ramayana from some Purana talks about it...but Ravana lusted over many, he himself admitted it in Valmiki Ramayana atleast for Vedavati and Rambha..

Answer (score 1):

Apart from lust for Vedavati and Rambha, Ravana had molested Dvaipayana's sister, Atri's wife, Rtuvarman's wife Madanamanjari, Agni's wife Svaha, Brihaspati's daughter Sulekha and God Brahma's daughter Punjika [Ref: Puranic Encyclopedia page 646].

As per folklore, Ravana had also raped Rishi Udanga’s daughter Malati on the banks of River Godavari.

Ravana had even cast his evil eye on Goddess Lakshmi in the higher regions. He was dumped back on Earth by God Vishnu, as he remained protected by God Brahma’s boon [Ref: Ramayana 7.28].

Source: 'Essence of the Fifth Veda' by Gaurang Damani page 16

I have not yet read in any Purana about Goddess Parvati in reference to the wretchedness of Ravana.

But they would have been contemporaries as per a folklore. At Thirumandhamkunnu temple in Malappuram district of Kerala state, Parvati had met King Mandhata as he had placed Her favourite Shiva-linga there. Mandhata was a contemporary of Ravana.